# Typing on my Android Device directly from Windows 10

Tags: external-keyboard

Is there a way where I can type something on Windows 10 and it goes directly to my ZTE Axon 7?

Comment: You can always use an otg wire and connect a keyboard to your phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try [Remote Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.onyxbits.remotekeyboard), available for Android 2.3+.

That app worked well with my Windows 10 computer and my OnePlus 3T, and you can try [this tutorial](http://www.onyxbits.de/remotekeyboard) which shows you how to use the app.

If you don't like this app or if it's not working with your phone, you can try this one : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.volosyukivan

Or, as [@A bochur](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/241679/a-bochur) said, you can use an OTG wire.